# Pulling a user's group membership list in Google Apps

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

I'm converting my application over to the directory API and am trying to find a way to pull a user's group membership in google using .NET.

Looking at the API page: [Google Apps API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members)

I see "Retrieve a Group's Member" that requires both a group and a member's key.  I can't find this call in the service.Groups functions.  I also looked at the service.Membership functions and I'm not finding anything.

Where is the API that pulls a single user's group membership?

Update:

This is the call I'm attempting to use:

```
        try
        {
            GroupsResource.ListRequest groups = service.Groups.List();
            groups.Domain = "appDomain.com";
            groups.Customer = strGoogleCusID;
            groups.MaxResults = 100;
            groups.PageToken = "";
            groups.UserKey = "User@appDomain.com";
            var list = groups.Execute();
        }
        catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
        {
        }
```

But it returns bad request.  I can use this function to return all groups in a domain, but if I specify the UserKey I get 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Are you using this client library? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1/

Comment: Yes, but I'm not finding the API call to pull a user's groups.  I can do all members of a group but not all groups for a user.

Comment: It seams like you need this one: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Admin_1_1Directory_1_1directory__v1_1_1MembersResource.html#abe791cc40b1793d758d8ec7209189985. So maybe it's service.Members.Get(*group_key*, *member_key*).ExecuteAsync() ? If so, let me know and I'll change this comment to be the answer.

Comment: No that just checks to see if the user is a member of a single group.

Comment: Can you find the right operation in the Google API explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/)?

Comment: I've looked there before as well.  I know their dir sync tool does this so there must be a call somewhere...

Comment: If there is no call there, the .NET client library (or any client library) won't be able to generate one for you :(

Comment: Not good... I can't believe they're making me convert off the old API without having all the functionality in the new API...

It has to be possibly somehow, the google ad sync tool does this.

Comment: Is this resolved already? I got the very same problem, even in the "Try It" Section here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list#auth

Comment: Yes, I used Sayali's answer/link...  It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Groups -> list API where a userKey can be specified.  It returns all the groups the user is a memberOf.  Here's the link - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list

Comment: That looks like it may have the right call but the .net API doesnt' seem to pull the group list down; I get a 400 Bad Request.  See the code at the bottom of my updated question.

Comment: Ok, there appears to be a bug in the call.  If you call this function with the customer ID it fails (it should be callable according to the API link you have above).  But if I use a domain I can get the groups.  The problem is, I have to use the customer ID, my program does domain aliases...  Any ideas?

Comment: @DaBlue, did you get over this? If I provide both customer id and userKey I get a 400 error, if I provide just one or other then it works.

Comment: I didn't have time to deal with it so I pulled all group memberships to cache then processed locally with linq...

Answer (score 1):

```
def retrieving_groups():

    response_group = service.groups().list(customer='my_customer').execute()
    for group in response_group['groups']:
        print(group['email'])
```

here the function, it will return all email addresses of all groups

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here but might post it in case anyone needs it.. This is something I found pretty frustrating.

```
Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.GroupsResource.ListRequest lr = new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.GroupsResource.ListRequest(dirservice);

lr.UserKey = "USER_EMAIL_HERE";

foreach (Group gmem in lr.Execute().GroupsValue)
{
    Console.Writeline(gmem.Email.ToString() + '\n');
}
```

The lr.Execute().GroupsValue will return a list of Group objects, and I just iterate through it accordingly.

EDIT:

Also take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Admin_1_1Directory_1_1directory__v1_1_1GroupsResource_1_1ListRequest.html) - I think you may want to omit using the "domain" property and use the "Customer" one instead.. (if I understand the requirements correctly).

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<Group> g = groupsResourceRequest.Execute().GroupsValue;

this.GroupList.DataSource = g.Select(x => x.Email).ToList();
```

But, even in the above way, this method has an upper limit of 200. Please tell me how someone can get over 200.